# SOLR boost query not working when indexing and searching goes together

Tags: solr, solr-boost

- I am trying to apply boost query in solr 5.5 which is not working as
  desired. In our case we are indexing data to solr at real time and at
  the same time we are searching the data.even after setting autoCommit
  to 1 second its not working. boost query only works when whole data
  get indexed

Comment: What's your query? Whats the `debugQuery=true` output for that query? What did you expect to happen? How are you retrieving the documents?

Comment: thanks for quick response.
I am scrapping and indexing document to solr with ruby and at the wait of 3 second I am searching the indexed doc with java,but all threads are not done with indexing yet and in this case boost query is not working because of which I am not getting relevant documents resultset

Comment: It's impossible to answer what's happening unless you add relevant information to your question - i.e. what doesn't work for the boost query? Is there documents matching that query committed to the index? Have you tried using `commitWithin` instead of autocommit? Do you have an example of what fails?

Comment: I am searching documents using query like **searchid:"some id"** AND boost query like **bq=tile:some Title^10** .There are matched document but the relevant docs are not boosting up because at the same time ruby threads are still writing data with same **searchId**  . **commitWithin** is as default having following configuratio

**<autoSoftCommit> 
         <maxTime>500</maxTime> 
       </autoSoftCommit>**

Comment: As far as I know the fact that there are still documents being written shouldn't affect boosting in any way; only that commits have taken place (i.e. the documents have been made available in the index). If you're able to reproduce this with a simple setup (i.e. using curl instead), feel free to add details to your question (... and the details given in comments should be added to your question).